# How to train new data set in multivariate linear regression?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

Suppose I have 2 million previous training examples , I had already spent  time in training my model with these examples . Now I receive another 100 examples . So would I have to train again those 2 million examples with these 100 examples or just somehow remember the parameters (weights) obtained from initial training and use them in training 100 examples ?

Comment: It depends on the type of learning. If you are using batch learning, you have to retrain your model by augmenting the new data to your old data set. While, if you are using online learning, you can use your first model weights and further update them using the new data.

Comment: @Riyaz  Again online leaning such as stochastic gradient descent  uses whole training data set , then does random shuffling of whole data set but in updating the parameter uses only single data point , so how do we run it using only new examples ?

Comment: Use your original weights as initial weights for the new model. Then train your model with SGD using only the new data.

Comment: Can't this be done in batch learning also ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes actually LR is an online learning model,so you can use your last parameter as the initial weights when you train the new 200 examples